# How to append a list of Hex to one Hex number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of hex bytes strings like this

```
['0xe1', '0xd7', '0x7', '0x0']
```

(as read from a binary file)

I want to flip the list and append the list together to create one hex number,

```
['0x07D7E1']
```

How do I format the list to this format?

Comment: Do you mean '0x07D7E1' or '0x07D71E'?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: Why `07d71e`? The input starts with `e1`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh sorry I misread. I thought the individual inputs were being reversed as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate your hex numbers into one string:

```
'0x' + ''.join([format(int(c, 16), '02X') for c in reversed(inputlist)])
```

This does include the `00` byte explicitly in the output:

```
>>> inputlist = ['0xe1', '0xd7', '0x7', '0x0']
>>> '0x' + ''.join([format(int(c, 16), '02X') for c in reversed(inputlist)])
'0x0007D7E1'
```

However, I'd look into reading your binary file format better; using `struct` for example to unpack bytes directly from the file into proper integers in the right byte order:

```
>>> import struct
>>> bytes = ''.join([chr(int(c, 16)) for c in inputlist])
>>> value = struct.unpack('<I', bytes)[0]
>>> print hex(value)
0x7d7e1
```